# Controller AJAX method to return AJAX ActionLink

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax

I am fairly new to MVC and just trying to achieve something which I think shouldn't be too complicated to achieve. Just want to know what the best approach for that is. I have an Event-RSVP application (NerdDinner kind) where you go to view details of the event and then click on an AJAX link that will RSVP you for the event.

```
    <% 
    if (Model.HasRSVP(Context.User.Identity.Name))
    {
    %>
    <p>
    You are registered for this event!&nbsp;            
    <%: 
    Ajax.ActionLink("Click here if you can't make it!", "CancelRegistration", "RSVP", new { id = Model.RSVPs.FirstOrDefault(r => r.AttendeeName.ToLower() == User.Identity.Name.ToLower()).RSVPID }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "QuickRegister"}) 
    %>
    </p>
    <% 
    }
    else
    { 
    %>
    <p>
    <%: 
Ajax.ActionLink("RSVP for this event", "Register", "RSVP", new { id=Model.EventID }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId="QuickRegister" }) %>
    </p>
    <% 
    } 
    %>
```

Now corresponding to these two links, my functions in RSVP Controller look like these.

```
[Authorize, HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(int id)
{
    Event event = eventRepository.GetEvent(id);

    if (event == null)
        return Content("Event not found");

    if (!event.IsUserRegistered(User.Identity.Name))
    {
        RSVP rsvp = new RSVP();
        rsvp.AttendeeName = User.Identity.Name;
        event.RSVPs.Add(rsvp);
        eventRepository.Save();            
    }

    return Content("Thanks, you are registered.");

}

[Authorize, HttpPost]
public ActionResult CancelRegistration(int id)
{
    RSVP rsvp = eventRepository.GetRSVP(id);    

    if (rsvp == null)
        return Content("RSVP not found");

    if (rsvp.Event.IsUserRegistered(User.Identity.Name))
    {
        eventRepository.DeleteRSVP(rsvp);
        eventRepository.Save();
    }

    return Content("Sorry, we won't be seeing you there!");
}
```

Both of these seem to work without any issues. Now I want to make it a little fancier by doing either of these two:

1) Return an AJAX link from controller so that when you register, you get cancel registration link shown to you without page refresh.

2) Somehow make the view rendering refreshed when the controller method has finished executing so the first code block in my question gets executed after the click of any of the AJAX links. So clicking on register will register you and show you cancel link and clicking on cancel will cancel your registration and show you register link.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: After the confusion in the comments below, here is some more explanation. What I want to be able to do is have 1) you are not subscribed (text) & click to rsvp (link) 2) you are subscribed (text) & click to cancel (link) displayed alternatively based on the user's current RSVP status. There is no specific requirement from client to do this, this is a part of my learning ASP .Net MVC and I just want to understand what options I have. From your comments below, it looks like jquery $.post() is the way to go. So I will now further investigate and see if I have any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could by using jQuery show and hide these links.

I never use the Ajax.ActionLink, I do my AJAX without the helper but I think it should look loke this :

```
Ajax.ActionLink("Click here if you can't make it!", "CancelRegistration", "RSVP", new { id = Model.RSVPs.FirstOrDefault(r => r.AttendeeName.ToLower() == User.Identity.Name.ToLower()).RSVPID }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "QuickRegister", OnSuccess = "ShowHideLinks" }, new { id = "cancel-link", @style = "display:none"})
Ajax.ActionLink("RSVP for this event", "Register", "RSVP", new { id=Model.EventID }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId="QuickRegister", OnSuccess = "ShowHideLinks" }, new { id = "register-link"})
```

And some javascript/jQuery to initialize the current display link :

```
        function ShowHideLinks() {
            $('#register-link').toggle();
            $('#cancel-link').toggle();
        }
        <%: if(Model.HasRSVP(Context.User.Identity.Name)) { %>
            ShowHideLinks();
        <%: } %>
```

Hope this help!

Comment: I don't think this approach would work because the content is dynamic. Basically I want it to work so that the part of the view I am clicking the link from gets updated after the click.

Comment: what you want to show in your updated part? you need to provide us with more information. I also think that you should use jQuery $.post() and not Ajax.ActionLink. You might also want to take a look at jQuery Template if your data is complex, you don't want to return HTML in your controller : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.template/

Comment: Thank you, I have added a comment to my question hoping it would make things clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the links using jQuery. I see you are passing Content from  both the action methods... You can use $.post() in jQuery to execute these action and in the success eventhandler compare the returned content (you would need to send something which is more easy to compare than the current strings) and set the links appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That would work but will require some changes to the way the page works. What if I want the data displayed on the page to be dynamic based on whether or not the user is registered. Please correct me if I have not understood your response properly.

Comment: As you said - you don't the page to refereshed you would need to do some changes in the code. However - when you say the data displayed on the page to be dynamic - you can acheive it from your current actions by passing context (inline html) and rendering it on the page..

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I don't want to send inline html from controller. I will use jquery $.post() as mentioned by @VinnyG below.