# How can I replace (or update) an Ajax.ActionLink with another Ajax.ActionLink?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, actionlink

Let's say I have a list of users:

**User/Index.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcHoist.Models.UserProfileViewModel>

<table>
    @foreach (var user in Model)
    {
        @Html.Partial("_User", user)
    }
</table>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

...and (using a partial) next to each user is a "Follow" or "Unfollow" link, as appropriate:

**_User.cshtml partial**

```
@model MvcHoist.Models.UserProfileViewModel
<tr>
    <td>
        @if (Model.IsFollowed)
        {
            @Ajax.ActionLink("Unfollow", "Unfollow", new { id = Model.UserProfile.UserId }, new AjaxOptions
               {
                   HttpMethod = "POST"
               })
        }
        else
        {
            @Ajax.ActionLink("Follow", "Follow", new { id = Model.UserProfile.UserId }, new AjaxOptions
               {
                   HttpMethod = "POST"
               })
        }
    </td>
</tr>
```

**How can I replace the "Follow" Ajax.ActionLink with an "Unfollow" Ajax.ActionLink after the Follow action has completed successfully?**  Using a single Ajax.ActionLink by changing the `linkText` and `actionName` would be fine, too.

Can this be done purely with Ajax.ActionLink (without diving too deeply into jQuery)?  Animating the change would be even better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the @if (...) condition, render both links, but render the second link with a style of "display:none;".

The style attributes might look something like this:

```
..., new { style="display:@(Model.IsFollowed ? "block" : "none")" }, ...
..., new { style="display:@(Model.IsFollowed ? "none" : "block")" }, ...
```

Add an OnComplete handler or a little bit of jQuery (or alternative) to toggle both links upon success.

For the animation, you could use the jQuery fadeIn() and fadeOut() functions.

Answer (score 2):

While I would have liked a pure Ajax.ActionLink solution (if possible), @SimonGoldstone's more jQuery-based approach ([similar to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5545969/103058)) gets the job done.  Here's how it turned out:

**User/Index.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcHoist.Models.UserProfileViewModel>

<table>
    @foreach (var user in Model)
    {
        @Html.Partial("_User", user)
    }
</table>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

    <script>
        var toggleFollowUnfollowLinks = function (followLink, unfollowLink) {
            // based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/5545969/103058 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/19689745/103058
            var fout = followLink.is(":visible") ? followLink : unfollowLink;
            var fin = !followLink.is(":visible") ? followLink : unfollowLink;

            fout.fadeOut("fast", function () {
                fin.fadeIn();
            });
        };
    </script>
}
```

**_User.cshtml partial**

```
@model MvcHoist.Models.UserProfileViewModel

@{
    var unfollowLinkId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    var followLinkId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    var onSuccess = String.Format("toggleFollowUnfollowLinks($('#{0}'), $('#{1}'))", followLinkId, unfollowLinkId);
}

<tr>
    <td>
        @Ajax.ActionLink("Unfollow", "Unfollow", new { id = Model.UserProfile.UserId }, new AjaxOptions
               {
                   HttpMethod = "POST",
                   OnSuccess = @onSuccess
               }, new { id = @unfollowLinkId, @style = @Model.IsFollowed ? "display:block" : "display:none" })

        @Ajax.ActionLink("Follow", "Follow", new { id = Model.UserProfile.UserId }, new AjaxOptions
               {
                   HttpMethod = "POST",
                   OnSuccess = @onSuccess
               }, new { id = @followLinkId, @style = !@Model.IsFollowed ? "display:block" : "display:none" })
    </td>
</tr>
```

Generating unique IDs (using Guid.NewGuid()) was necessary to prevent an action on e.g. the third row from affecting the Ajax.ActionLink in the first row.